# Java MySql update issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using following code for my program to update the necessary data. However when the update button is clicked my data is not updating. When I check the database it shows empty database fields. I can't figure out why my code is not working. I use the search option to load the data before updating them. Search function works perfectly. Any ideas on fixing this.

```
    private void btn_update2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE `read_with_us`.`member_reg` SET `first_name`=?, `last_name`=?, `address`=?, `contact_number`=?, `email_address`=?, `member_type`=? WHERE `member_id`=?";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_fname.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_lname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_address.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txt_contactnumber.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txt_email.getText());
        String memtype = (String) com_membertype.getSelectedItem();
        pst.setString(6, memtype);
        pst.setString(7, txt_memberid2.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Sucessfully Updated");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

My database result:

[image: database result]

[image: Program interface]

[image: database structure]

Comment: do you see `"Record Sucessfully Updated"` message?

Comment: Yes but it only clears the fields.

Comment: what type of `member_id` ?

Comment: i don't see any code clearing the fields!? how they are cleaned? i thought some (a guess) `member_id` mostly will be `int`, so you may want to use `pst.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(txt_memberid2.getText()));` but mostly if this is an issue, there should be an exception for this, but try it anyway ...

Comment: can u make `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block please

Comment: Member Id is set as an integer.
@Yazan I tried your code but still the result is same.

Comment: i am not sure what else could be the reason, are you sure it's the same database (the one the code use, and the one checked by the tool)?

Comment: Yes @Yazan it's the same database, I have attached the db structure.

Comment: what type of `member_id` sorry i can't see the pictures !

Comment: I have set it as INT(10)

Comment: so try my solution above you have to use setInt make sure that `txt_memberid2.getText()` provide a correct int

Comment: I tried it but didn't work, not sure why it's not updating even with the modified code.

Comment: can u make `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block please and show us what it throw?

Comment: what is `read_with_us` and `member_reg` represent, schema and table or database and table?

Comment: `read_with_us` and `member_reg` represents schema and table.

`e.printStackTrace();` does not throw any messages.

Comment: can you print `txt_memberid2.getText()` ?